# Typekit font not working in facebook page

Tags: facebook, typekit

I am creating a facebook page that has to load typekit fonts in it.

In the kit editor of typekit, I had entered the url for the facebook app (url that appears when the app tab is open).

I then included the javascript from typekit on the facebook page.

But the fonts don't load. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar problem. The trick is to make sure that the fonts are allowed everywhere they could be loaded. There's a setting on Typekit for each typekit that you own where you can specify allowed domains. It might look something like this:

```
facebook.com,localhost,*.facebook.com,myapp.herokuapp.com,*.myapp.herokuapp.com
```

I'm not sure if you'll need all of those, but that setup works for me. "localhost" is for my local dev environment, and myapp.herokuapp.com is where my application is hosted.